# .htaccess and A record subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have a wordpress hosting account. I also have a standard web hosting account with the same host. My main website, domain.com is hosted on the Wordpress platform, BUT now I want to add a subdomain for sub.domain.com.

I can't host the script on sub.domain.com as part of the wordpress hosting, so I have been told to create it on my standard web hosting account and then use an `A` record in the DNS for domain.com to point to the IP of sub.domain.com.

Now, all this works if I visit `http://sub.domain.com`. However, `www.sub.domain.com` doesn't work.

What I want to know is, can I edit the .htaccess for domain.com to redirect anyone who visits `www.sub.domain.com` to `http://sub.domain.com`?

Comment: it is very **uncommon** to use www with a subdomain and is actually pretty useless. 99% of people will never try to use that unless you give it to them or provide a link to it. Ed is right I wouldn't waste my time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use .htaccess to redirect traffic from `www.sub.domain.com` to `sub.domain.com`, because that traffic won't ever get to your server unless your DNS is set up correctly. In other words, if there's no DNS record for `www.sub.domain.com`, traffic looking for that address will never hit your server, so what is in your .htaccess would be irrelevant.

Keep in mind that you don't have to have `www.sub.domain.com` - almost nobody will visit that unless you share links using that domain yourself.

**That said, if you really want to do this:**

- Create a sub-sub domain by creating an `A` record for `www.sub.domain.com`
- Edit the .htaccess file for that sub-sub domain only, adding this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```